# What is an efficient C++ container for at most one object

Tags: c++, containers

I'd like to have a container that may contain either 0 or 1 object of class T. It could be implemented with a class that contains just one pointer, with proper destructor, copy constructor, assignment operator (and move operator for C++11). Smart pointers don't work because I want a copy to make a copy of the object. std::vector is inefficient because it has more data and logic than required. I could implement such a container myself, but I wonder if there is a ready-made solution.

Edit to make things clearer: my motivation is to save memory when the container is empty, because my T is big. So boost::optional does not work.

Comment: [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: @HansPassant I can't imagine you being afraid of a little pointer.

Comment: I think he was suggesting "A pointer" to "What is an efficient C++ container"

Comment: Thanks Dieter. I am now trying to read the implementation to understand them. The implementation of std::vector for gcc holds 3 pointers (start, finish, end_of_storage). I don't understand yet very well the implementation of boost::optional, but I now understand it does not do what I want: it simply stores the object together with a boolean. My motivation is to save memory when the container is empty, so it does not work.

Comment: Just use std::vector (the overhead is negligible) or make your own container to spare some members (size an capacity).

Comment: I don't know of a ready-made solution - but if you do implement your own you could inherit from std::unique_ptr (which can be empty and also does most of the housekeeping for you), and then add on your own copy constructor and assignment operator to get the "copy to make a copy of the object" semantics that you are after.

Comment: I don't really get why you don't use a pointer? 4 bytes is pretty light isn't it?

Comment: I will use a pointer, but I need to implement the assignment operator, copy constructor, and destructor. It is not difficult to do, but I thought such a simple pattern may be available ready-made.